# Named parameters passing incorrectly through ajax call (Js helper) in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, jquery, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to make an ajax call by passing named parameters:

```
$this->Js->link('Save',array(
                          'controller' => 'screens', 
                          'action' => 'create') + $this->params['named'], 
                       array( 'update' => '#results'));
```

However the named parameters passed in above call are incorrect (though they are correct when passed without ajax):

Example results:

**Without Ajax:** http://paste.ubuntu.com/546338/
**With Ajax:** http://paste.ubuntu.com/546337/

Escaping the Ajax URL might help, but how can I do that (or some other way) ?

P.S. : the problem persists only with the Js Helper, if I use the Ajax helper then the data passes correctly. However, the Ajax helper is depreciated and is not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Leo means is this:

```
$this->Js->link('save', array('url'=>array('controller'=>'blah', 'action'=>'foo', $this->params['named']), 'update'=>'div'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing the $url array outside of the method call. I've found array arithmetic to be unreliable at the best of times. A side effect will be that you'll be able to `debug($url);` to make sure all is well.

Comment: Hi Leo, the URL constructs reliably, here is the output http://bin.cakephp.org/view/122471414 .